# Cannot plot datetime64[ns] on hvplot axis ('pandas_datetime_types' is not defined' error)

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews, hvplot

I am simply trying to plot some values against datetime64[ns] timestamps with holoviews.
That is,
x-axis = nx1 datetime64[ns] values
y-axis = nx1 data.

Here is a screen shot of what I have:

[Screenshot of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MZRs.png)

`<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

and my overall code:

```
import hvplot.pandas
import pandas as pd


##
Code ommitted at the start to extract data and create dictionary to convert to data frame
##

#create dictionary
temp_dict = dict(sampling_time=time_y_value_is_taken, y_axis_values = y_values)

df = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(temp_dict)
df.sampling_time=df.sampling_time.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df=df.set_index('sampling_time')

##The following code cannot run this line- it throws error
df.hvplot.line()
```

I keep getting the error code : 'pandas_datetime_types' is not defined. I have also tried importing datetime as datetime - but it does not work.

EDIT: Here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\dimension.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, include, exclude)
   1315         combined and returned.
   1316         """
-> 1317         return Store.render(self)
   1318 
   1319 

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\options.py in render(cls, obj)
   1403         data, metadata = {}, {}
   1404         for hook in hooks:
-> 1405             ret = hook(obj)
   1406             if ret is None:
   1407                 continue

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in pprint_display(obj)
    280     if not ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].pprint:
    281         return None
--> 282     return display(obj, raw_output=True)
    283 
    284 

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in display(obj, raw_output, **kwargs)
    250     elif isinstance(obj, (CompositeOverlay, ViewableElement)):
    251         with option_state(obj):
--> 252             output = element_display(obj)
    253     elif isinstance(obj, (Layout, NdLayout, AdjointLayout)):
    254         with option_state(obj):

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in wrapped(element)
    144         try:
    145             max_frames = OutputSettings.options['max_frames']
--> 146             mimebundle = fn(element, max_frames=max_frames)
    147             if mimebundle is None:
    148                 return {}, {}

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in element_display(element, max_frames)
    190         return None
    191 
--> 192     return render(element)
    193 
    194 

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in render(obj, **kwargs)
     66         renderer = renderer.instance(fig='png')
     67 
---> 68     return renderer.components(obj, **kwargs)
     69 
     70 

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py in components(self, obj, fmt, comm, **kwargs)
    408                 doc = Document()
    409                 with config.set(embed=embed):
--> 410                     model = plot.layout._render_model(doc, comm)
    411                 if embed:
    412                     return render_model(model, comm)

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in _render_model(self, doc, comm)
    453         if comm is None:
    454             comm = state._comm_manager.get_server_comm()
--> 455         model = self.get_root(doc, comm)
    456 
    457         if config.embed:

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in get_root(self, doc, comm, preprocess)
    510         """
    511         doc = init_doc(doc)
--> 512         root = self._get_model(doc, comm=comm)
    513         if preprocess:
    514             self._preprocess(root)

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py in _get_model(self, doc, root, parent, comm)
    120         if root is None:
    121             root = model
--> 122         objects = self._get_objects(model, [], doc, root, comm)
    123         props = dict(self._init_params(), objects=objects)
    124         model.update(**self._process_param_change(props))

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py in _get_objects(self, model, old_objects, doc, root, comm)
    110             else:
    111                 try:
--> 112                     child = pane._get_model(doc, root, model, comm)
    113                 except RerenderError:
    114                     return self._get_objects(model, current_objects[:i], doc, root, comm)

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\holoviews.py in _get_model(self, doc, root, parent, comm)
    237             plot = self.object
    238         else:
--> 239             plot = self._render(doc, comm, root)
    240 
    241         plot.pane = self

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\holoviews.py in _render(self, doc, comm, root)
    304                 kwargs['comm'] = comm
    305 
--> 306         return renderer.get_plot(self.object, **kwargs)
    307 
    308     def _cleanup(self, root):

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\renderer.py in get_plot(self_or_cls, obj, doc, renderer, **kwargs)
     71         combining the bokeh model with another plot.
     72         """
---> 73         plot = super(BokehRenderer, self_or_cls).get_plot(obj, doc, renderer, **kwargs)
     74         if plot.document is None:
     75             plot.document = Document() if self_or_cls.notebook_context else curdoc()

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py in get_plot(self_or_cls, obj, doc, renderer, comm, **kwargs)
    241             init_key = tuple(v if d is None else d for v, d in
    242                              zip(plot.keys[0], defaults))
--> 243             plot.update(init_key)
    244         else:
    245             plot = obj

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py in update(self, key)
    980     def update(self, key):
    981         if len(self) == 1 and ((key == 0) or (key == self.keys[0])) and not self.drawn:
--> 982             return self.initialize_plot()
    983         item = self.__getitem__(key)
    984         self.traverse(lambda x: setattr(x, '_updated', True))

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\element.py in initialize_plot(self, ranges, plot, plots, source)
   1388             element = self.hmap.last
   1389         key = util.wrap_tuple(self.hmap.last_key)
-> 1390         ranges = self.compute_ranges(self.hmap, key, ranges)
   1391         self.current_ranges = ranges
   1392         self.current_frame = element

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py in compute_ranges(self, obj, key, ranges)
    636             if (not (axiswise and not isinstance(obj, HoloMap)) or
    637                 (not framewise and isinstance(obj, HoloMap))):
--> 638                 self._compute_group_range(group, elements, ranges, framewise,
    639                                           axiswise, robust, self.top_level,
    640                                           prev_frame)

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py in _compute_group_range(cls, group, elements, ranges, framewise, axiswise, robust, top_level, prev_frame)
    853                     continue
    854                 matching &= (
--> 855                     len({'date' if isinstance(v, util.datetime_types) else 'number'
    856                          for rng in rs for v in rng if util.isfinite(v)}) < 2
    857                 )

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\plot.py in <setcomp>(.0)
    854                 matching &= (
    855                     len({'date' if isinstance(v, util.datetime_types) else 'number'
--> 856                          for rng in rs for v in rng if util.isfinite(v)}) < 2
    857                 )
    858             if matching:

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\util.py in isfinite(val)
    902         return finite
    903     elif isinstance(val, datetime_types+timedelta_types):
--> 904         return not isnat(val)
    905     elif isinstance(val, (basestring, bytes)):
    906         return True

~\miniconda3\envs\mpess_visual\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\util.py in isnat(val)
    866     elif pd and val is pd.NaT:
    867         return True
--> 868     elif pd and isinstance(val, pandas_datetime_types+pandas_timedelta_types):
    869         return pd.isna(val)
    870     else:

NameError: name 'pandas_datetime_types' is not defined
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Comment: Hi @CristiFati, Just edited my post and attached the traceback, thank you

Comment: What are your *HoloViews* and *Pandas* versions? Also are ther any warnings in your script?

Comment: @CristiFati The versions are Holoviews=1.14.4 and Pandas = 1.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I couldn't find any official *doc* to support my statement, it's a compatibility issue (*HoloViews 1.14.4* was released before *Pandas 1.3.0*).

Looking at [[gitHub]: holoviz/holoviews - (v1.14.4) holoviews/holoviews/core/util.py](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/blob/v1.14.4/holoviews/core/util.py) (starting with line *#83*), there are some conditional imports. One of them is ***ABCIndexClass***.

[[GitHub]: pandas-dev/pandas - (v1.3.0) pandas/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.0/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py)  on the other hand, does **not** provide it (as opposed from let's say its ***v1.2.5*** counterpart) yielding (silent) exception, and the behavior you're experiencing.

Ways to go:

- Upgrade *HoloViews* to ***v1.14.5*** which no longer has this problem, (or at least, there's a *Pandas 1.3.0* conditional as well - fixed by [[GitHub]: holoviz/holoviews - Add support for pandas>=1.3](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/pull/5013))
- You could also downgrade *Pandas* to (*e.g.*) *v1.2.5*, although this is not the way to go